# How to plot array of coordinates on image using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I'm trying to plot an array of coordinates using matplotlib.
x & y are two arrays with x and y coordinates.

Sample Data:

`x = [489.99378204345703, 424.4607162475586, 665.4505157470703, 665.1176452636719]`
`y = [709.4012403488159, 253.38330745697021, 519.5582628250122, 519.5164632797241]`

**This is the code I'm using to plot**

```
im = plt.imread(p_transform_path)
implot = plt.imshow(im)
for p,q in zip(x,y):
    x_cord = x[p]
    y_cord = y[q]
    plt.scatter([x_cord], [y_cord])
plt.show()
```

`p_transform_path` is the path of the image on which I'm plotting the coordinates.
This is the error message:

```
x_cord = x[p]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
im = plt.imread(p_transform_path)
implot = plt.imshow(im)
for p,q in zip(x,y):
    x_cord = p # try this change (p and q are already the coordinates)
    y_cord = q
    plt.scatter([x_cord], [y_cord])
plt.show()
```